# Huawei Push Exception: com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907122037: get token error

Tags: java, android, token, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I can't create Huawei Push token.

1. `TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 907122012` - when `push_kit_auto_init_enabled=true` in manifest
2. `String: com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907122037: get token error` - when i trying to get token manually in

   ```
   String huaweiappid = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(context).getId();
   String huaweitoken = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(context).getToken(huaweiappid, "HCM");

   //this is stacktrace
   com.huawei.hms.aaid.constant.ErrorEnum.toApiException(ErrorEnum.java:1)
   com.huawei.hms.opendevice.l.a(GetTokenTask.java:5)
   com.huawei.hms.opendevice.l.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:1)
   com.huawei.hms.common.internal.TaskApiCall.onResponse(TaskApiCall.java:5)
   com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager$1.onCallback(HuaweiApiManager.java:18)
   com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$BaseAdapterCallBack.doCallback(HmsClient.java:5)
   com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HmsClient$BaseAdapterCallBack.onComplete(HmsClient.java:1)
   com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.handleSolutionIntent(BaseAdapter.java:16)
   com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:104)
   com.huawei.hms.adapter.BaseAdapter$BaseRequestResultCallback.onResult(BaseAdapter.java:1)
   com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$d.b(PendingResultImpl.java:1)
   com.huawei.hms.support.api.PendingResultImpl$d.handleMessage(PendingResultImpl.java:4)
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
   ```

How can i get my Huawei client's token?

Comment: This isn't a stack-trace.

Comment: hi@alexbayker, could you please leave your appid and provide your complete log, so that we can analyse your problem.

Comment: Also pls check whether the Push Service Is Enabled. and whether your app has been transferred?

Comment: My appid is 104331235

Comment: hi@alexbayker, could you please provide your complete log for us to trace this issue?

Comment: Also whether your app has been transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved! I change my `build.gradle (app:)` for signing debug version with release keystore, clear app data and cache in HMS Core app. Manual: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-integrating-sdk-0000001050040084

Comment: Can you please explain how you resolved the issue i am not able to get the token @alexbayker

Comment: This is my build.gradle) https://pastebin.com/tXqhar7z